# Convergence of an improper integral of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm struggling to analyze an improper integral of two variables.

$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\int_1^y f(x)\sqrt{y-x}dx
$$
where $f$ is a real valued function defined on $[0,\infty)$.

One simple example $f(x)= 1$ does not make the integral converge.

I want to find some sufficient condition for the improper integral to be well defined.

My expected answer is like

$$
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} dx 
$$ 
is convergent $p>1$ and divergent $p<=1$.

Thank you for advance.

My question may be somewhat vague. Ask me freely for some points making you confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is any positive measurable function then the limit is $\infty$ by Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, $f$ is not restricted to a positive function.  :<

Comment: I doubt if any reasonable sufficient  condition can be found.